# Generic conversion of simple ADT to array

Tags: haskell

Given a sum type:

```
type PlayerId = String
data Location = Deck | Hand PlayerId
```

How can I write either of these two functions (I don't care which generic approach to take ... bonus points for helping me figure out which is more appropriate):

```
myF :: Generic a => a -> [String]
myF :: Data a => a -> [String]

-- roughly equivalent to
myF :: Location -> [String]
myF x = case x of
          Deck     -> ["deck"]
          Hand pid -> ["hand", show pid]
```

(For any "invalid" type, e.g. the argument is not `Show`able, either return `[]` or `error`.)

Context: I have a number of similar enum-like types that I want to generically define `Data.Aeson.ToJSON` instances for, though given `myF` above I know how to do the rest. Though mostly I'm just doing this to learn more about generic programming.

**Attempts:**

**Using `Generic`**

```
λ> unM1 $ from Deck
(L1 (M1 {unM1 = U1}))

λ> :t (undefined :: Rep Location p)
(undefined :: Rep Location p)
  :: D1
       ('MetaData "Location" "Test" "main" 'False)
       (
         C1 ('MetaCons "Deck" 'PrefixI 'False) U1
         :+:
         C1
           ('MetaCons "Hand" 'PrefixI 'False)
           (S1
              ('MetaSel
                 'Nothing 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
              (Rec0 String)))
```

Since `:+:` is defined as `L1 | R1`, I could probably "merge" the above two results. I'm not sure of a neat way I'd do this though .. maybe pattern match on the former and use it to "descend" in to the latter - but I'm not sure how to cross over between the type definition and real code.

**Using `Data`**

AFAICT `Data` is an alternate approach to generics. You would use *either* `Generic` *or* `Data`, right?

I think I need to use one of the `gmap*` functions, but I can't figure out how to relate the types to my problem. Have tried some exploratory "plug random arguments in to various methods" but didn't get anywhere interesting.

*UPDATE!* I tried to simplify my example, but I may have done so too much. In my actual code, `PlayerId` is a newtype around string. The following "works" in that case (modulo lower casing the constructor name):

```
mkQ :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => r -> (b -> r) -> a -> r
(r `mkQ` q) a = case cast a of
                  Just b -> q b
                  Nothing -> r

myF :: Data a => a -> [String]
myF input =
  [showConstr . toConstr $ input]
  ++ gmapQ (\x -> ("" `mkQ` f) x) input

f :: PlayerId -> String
f (PlayerId x) = x
```

The insight here was that constructors and arguments need to be treated differently. A remaining problem is that the above code needs to know about `PlayerId`. The following doesn't work:

```
f :: Show a => a -> String
f = show
```

... since that doesn't match the type signature of `gmapQ`. I think I understand why this is the case: the way gmapQ works is by using `cast` and this definition of `f` isn't concrete enough to give it an actual type to cast to. I'm not sure if there is a way around this, or if it is a limitation of using `Data`. (This is still probably workable though, if not ideal: I can imagine a case where I have `myF` parameterized by some `fs` that are specific to the particular arguments in the type.)

It also doesn't feel right because I copied the `mkQ` function from the [original SYB paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2003/01/hmap.pdf) ... I would have thought I should be able to do this using functions provided by `Data.Data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using generics you don't need to merge two types of information. All you need is to handle each possible type via instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import GHC.Generics

type PlayerId = String
data Location = Deck | Hand PlayerId deriving Generic

instance MyClass Location

class MyClass a where
  myF :: a -> [String]
  default myF :: (Generic a, MyClass1 (Rep a)) => a -> [String]
  myF = defaultMyF

defaultMyF :: (Generic a, MyClass1 (Rep a)) => a -> [String]
defaultMyF a = myF1 $ from a
```

`Rep a` has kind `* -> *` so we cannot implement `MyClass` directly for `U1`, `V1`, `M1` etc. Instead we need another class where `myF` would have type `:: a b -> [String]`.

```
class MyClass1 a where
  myF1 :: a b -> [String]

instance MyClass1 V1 where
  myF1 _ = []

instance MyClass1 U1 where
  myF1 _ = []

instance MyClass1 (K1 i String) where
  myF1 (K1 a) = [a]

instance (MyClass1 f, Constructor t) => MyClass1 (C1 t f) where
  myF1 c@(M1 a) = (conName c) : myF1 a

instance (MyClass1 f) => MyClass1 (D1 t f) where
  myF1 (M1 a) = myF1 a


instance (MyClass1 f) => MyClass1 (S1 t f) where
  myF1 (M1 a) = myF1 a

instance (MyClass1 a, MyClass1 b) => MyClass1 (a :+: b) where
  myF1 (L1 x) = myF1 x
  myF1 (R1 x) = myF1 x

instance (MyClass1 a, MyClass1 b) => MyClass1 (a :*: b) where
  myF1 (a :*: b) = myF1 a ++ myF1 b
```

And now you can test it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ myF Deck
  putStrLn $ show $ myF $ Hand "1234"
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. It also means I can use a typeclass (e.g. `Show a`) rather than a concrete `String` for the implementation piece - which is a limitation I was running into with the `Data` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass, DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Char
import Generics.SOP
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC

type PlayerId = String
data Location = Deck | Hand PlayerId
  deriving (GHC.Generic, Generic, HasDatatypeInfo)
```

The library uses its own generic representation which can either be derived automatically from the GHC `Generic` class or via Template Haskell. We use the former approach, which means we have to derive `GHC.Generic` via the `DeriveGeneric` extension and then SOP's `Generic` and `HasDatatypeInfo` classes via the `DeriveAnyClass` extension.

We now proceed in two steps. The first is just to get the name of the constructor of a value as a lowercase string (because that's what you used in the example). A variant of this function should really be in the library, but unfortunately, it isn't, so we have to define it ourselves:

```
lcConstructor :: forall a . (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a) => a -> String
lcConstructor x =
  hcollapse
    (hzipWith
      (\ c _ -> K (map toLower (constructorName c)))
      (constructorInfo (datatypeInfo (Proxy @a)))
      (unSOP (from x))
    )
```

In essence, `constructorInfo (datatypeInfo (Proxy @a))` constructs a table of all the constructor information for the type `a`. The call to `hzipWith` then selects the right components from the table (the one corresponding to the value `x` in question). Furthermore, we extract the name from the constructor info and turn it into lowercase characters.

We can test this part:

```
GHCi> lcConstructor Deck
"deck"
GHCi> lcConstructor (Hand "42")
"hand"
```

The remaining work is to get string representations of all the constructor arguments and append them to the constructor name:

```
myF :: (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All2 Show (Code a)) => a -> [String]
myF a =
  (lcConstructor a :) . hcollapse . hcmap (Proxy @Show) (mapIK show) . from $ a
```

Here, `from` turns the value into its representation, then `hcmap` turns all the arguments of the constructor into strings using `show`, then `hcollapse` extracts the results as a list of strings, and `(lcConstructor :)` prepends the name of the constructor.

```
GHCi> myF Deck
["deck"]
GHCi> myF (Hand "42")
["hand", "\"42\""]
```

Comment: oh nice, I haven't looked at this library yet. Thanks!